# Why my screen goes down from the CoordinatorLayout when I am applying layout behavior to its child?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, bottomsheetdialogfragment

The content that I am adding in this LinearLayout moves down on the screen when I use layout Behavior even if I add it in the XML : Below is my XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_bg"
            tools:context=".AddUPIID">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                android:text="Payment methods"
                android:textColor="#2D2B32"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/chevron_left"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingStart="14dp"
                    android:paddingTop="19dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/upi_icon_2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
                        android:text="Add UPI ID"
                        android:textColor="#2E2C8D"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/texthead_Enter_UPI"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="-1sp"
                        android:text="Enter UPI ID"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="Enter UPI Id"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColorHint="#7F7D83"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/texthead_Enter_UPI"
                        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                        android:text="Save UPI ID for future usage"
                        android:textColor="#2D2B32 "
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextText" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/check_box_bg"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextText"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Secured by "
                android:textColor="#888888"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/proceedButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/boxpay_copyright"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/proceedButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Verify and proceed payment"
                android:textColor="#ADACB0"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is my BottomSheetFragment Code :

```
package com.example.tray

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import com.example.tray.databinding.FragmentAddUPIIDBinding
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment

class AddUPIID : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddUPIIDBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentAddUPIIDBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        var checked = false
        dialog?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        binding.imageView3.setOnClickListener(){
            if(!checked) {
                binding.imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox)
                checked = true
            }
            else {
                binding.imageView3.setImageResource(0)
                checked = false
            }
        }
        binding.imageView2.setOnClickListener(){
            dismiss()
        }
        binding.proceedButton.isEnabled = false

        binding.editTextText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                Log.d("beforeTextChanged",s.toString())
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                val textNow = s.toString()
                Log.d("onTextChanged",s.toString())
                if(textNow.isNotBlank()){
                    binding.proceedButton.isEnabled = true
                    binding.proceedButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg)
                    binding.proceedButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                Log.d("afterTextChanged",s.toString())
            }

        })
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val bottomSheetConstraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout
        val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetConstraintLayout)
    }
    companion object {

    }
}
```

I tried adding LinearLayout and NestedScrollView also but still the same problem. But when I added layout behavior tag in the grandchild of CoordinatorLayout. The view becomes correct.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1dNH.png)